# Do starcraft 2 professional players play with minimal visual settings

Tags: starcraft-2

Recently, i had the pleasure of being teased into playing starcraft 2 by a good friend; he came home with an Alienware rig and i was convinced enough to give the game a go on my older and less powerful pc. The game launched without any fancy effects, playable (i'm waiting to see how much large battles will drive the machine in the ground) but definitely less gorgeous than what i saw on the Alienware: no flowing creep, now glowing crystals, etc.

Now I've heard at some times that some FPS players would use barebones display settings to some degree in order to play better

- Dialing down the visual clutter may help you discern what is going on, instead of blowing your eyes with particle effects
- It makes the game feel more fluid
- It allows for some interesting hacks (i remember some people configuring the skin of other players to a glowing skeleton in order to see them better in some environments)

So do some players play SC2 with minimal graphics settings? Is it something that is trendy in some communities (pro players) ? Is the game clearer at barebone settings (no gibbing, physics and particles)?

Comment: OP should do some research on this: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=138409, http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=188805 all have multiple answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people play on low graphics because they think that it can make cloaked/burrowed units easier to see.  I am not sure if this is true, but some people certainly believe it.  Check out this answer:

[Do the video settings affect the visibility of cloaked units?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81412/do-the-video-settings-affect-the-visibility-of-cloaked-units)

If you are watching someone's personal stream (and not MLG/DH/GSL), they may be playing on low graphics to help with their FPS for their stream.

Above all I think that it is just personal preference.

---

Quote from ROOTheognis ([source](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=188805)):

> its all preference but I feel like using low graphic settings with
>   High Model settings is the best for me. The high model setting shows
>   death animations so If you lose units they don't just disappear and
>   wont leave u clueless on where they went

---

Here are some pros that play on low, from 2011 ([source](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=188805)):

> **Idra**
>
> Textures - Low
>
> Graphics - Low
>
> **Ret**
>
> Textures - Ultra
>
> Graphics - Low
>
> **QXC**
>
> Textures - Low
>
> Graphics - Low
>
> **TLO**
>
> Textures - High
>
> Graphics - Custom ( Everything Low but Effects on Ultra )
>
> **Nestea**
>
> Textures - Low
>
> Graphics - Low

Comment: "`Pro's play on a 2x2 resolution. Some say that is "crazy" or "that is just 4 colored boxes wtf".....clearly they have not played at the pro level`"

Comment: I actually find it easier to see burrowed and cloaked units on higher settings interestingly.

Answer (score 7):

Some StarCraft players do play on minimal settings. The reason however is not removing visual clutter, as even on max settings there is very little. The reason is to drive up the framerate, because they fear the game might start to lag in battles where many units are involved. Considering these battles are one of the most important parts of the game, they want to be absolutely sure there will be no lag, so there are players with über-PCs who play on minimal.

---

**Edit:**

As there seems to be doubt in the comments about the possibility of lag on an über-PC, here are some calculations which maybe make it more plausible:

A progamer will have over 200 actions per minute (APM), often they will exceed 300 APM. That is 4-5 Actions *per second*. Assuming a standart framerate of 60 fps, that means one action every 12-15 frames. Furthermore, the APM will often skyrocket during battles, as they are very micro-intensive.

Perhaps now you can imagine that even the slightest lag will interfere with precise and fast unit control, which is vital during battles. If you play for money, you will want to erase the slightest possibility of losing a decisive battle due to lag.

Comment: I don't understand why would the game 'lag' with an "uber-PC" ? I have a cheap graphics card and I only get down to 1-2 FPS only in 4v4 games when 8 200-populated armies clash with full graphics. Fearing lag with an uber-PC is not a convincing answer for me.

Comment: This partial answer is actually very legitimate (there are many reasons for low settings). If you look on the arcade right now there is a unit preloader that will launch every possible game effect so that it is loaded into memory. At the pro level any lag at all can cost you your army and the game. You might be okay with 1-2 FPS when the armies clash in that scenario, but the slightest delay in actions will hurt. The best finely tuned bicycle can still slip a gear at a critical time.

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli Fearing lag with an uber-PC might not be a convincing answer to you, but all that proves is that you don't take this particular game as seriously as some others do.  No insult there.  You need to be able to step out of your mind, and into the head of the kinds of players who would agonize over building the perfect machine for this one game, regardless of the expense, and THEN kill all the visual appealing aspects of the game just to eek out tiny spurts of performance.  Since some people do actually do this, the mindset does exist.

Comment: Seems reasonable - professional gamers are subject to the same superstitions that all other gamers are.  Similarly, many professional FPS players play with vsync off *(or the settings turned down)*, because they (incorrectly) believe it will allow them to see the enemies turn the corner sooner.

Comment: I obviously left the parts out which points out my confusion:) Okay, I ofcourse know how important fps is to the professional players and how they can lose an entire game due to slight loss of  fps (@Sorean). This doesn't necessarily mean that I don't take the games seriously as well (@Bon Gart). The point I did not understand was, how come the high-end processors (like i7 processors which cost 1000-1500$) and high-end gpu's can be short on performance when it comes to 1v1 games? My point was: I have a mid-range rig that only lowers performance on 4v4 large army clash ++

Comment: ++ when the graphics are full, but how come high-end tech processors and gpu's come short for 1v1 matches?

@Bon Gart Morever, as I told that the comment doesn't necessarily prove that I do not take games seriously as others do. The point that I was trying to make was pointing out an extreme situation (lowest fps I can get) and I am **NOT** okay with that amount of fps. (No insult taken btw, this is not a defiance, just clarification). I have been watching pro players for a while now, and I think I can empathy enough. I know how they can lose a game. I made my point in my previous comment.

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli It's not about what *you* define as a performance loss.  It is about what the hard core gamer with the Uber-PC defines a performance loss as.  That was *my* point.  What you see as a motion blur, that HCGamer might obsess over as something he/she can clear.  Would you consider bringing your own mouse and keyboard into a internet/gaming cafe?  These guys would.  Empathy is one thing... but you'd really need to be able to obsess over these details to understand why.  It's like being able to actually be autistic, to understand an autistic individual.

Comment: @BonGart I see your point, and as an answer to one of your questions: Yes, I would bring my own mouse if not keyboard to an internet cafe, and not only would, i actually did when i had to back in time. So i think i can understand how they feel, i'm only seeking for the detailed technical information which actually describes the "performance loss" which a pro player would concern about. Therefore, by this detailed tech. info, i can understand if its an "actual" performance loss which is considerable, or just a superstition.

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli At that stage of things, you might be talking 1 to 5 FPS difference between what you might notice, and what a "professional" or competition gamer might notice.  It might not even *be* noticeable, but an assumed difference.  That gamer, believing he's got a frame or two over the competition's speed, might only need that for the confidence boost.  All that said, back in the day, I saw some Quake players dominate the field using the mediocre cafe hardware, when there were players bringing their own superior gear.

Comment: Pixel shaders will need to render each frame multiple passes for some effects. No matter how high end your PC, you'll have better responsiveness with low graphics settings.

Answer (score 2):

Many pro players play with low graphical settings for a few reasons.

Like some of you other guys wrote, its due to performance issues in the later state of the game. Many units, buildings and actions (APM), will increase the possibility of lag spikes during a battle.

Another reason is that your internet connection might suffer from higher graphical settings. So when they stream via Twitch, the possibility of lag increases unless they lower their graphic settings. You would believe that most have a powerful connection, but if your in a house on the same line with 5 other guys streaming, it is better to lower the graphics to avoid lag issues.

With that said, some people might just like, the low res. game style.

I stream on Twitch myself, and always lower my graphical settings while streaming.
It demands a lot to stream, and lag issues increase if I dont.

Sorry for the un-sourced statements.
But its from firsthand experience and from a few friends that stream as well.

EDIT:
A lot of player including myself, use the arcade map called "Unit preloader" now, which loads all animations in the game making rendering more smooth.